# Как программно отследить, что заканчивается память?

Tags: windows, delphi, память

Можно ли это в конструкторе объекта как-то опросить, хватит ли памяти на его создание? Сейчас отлавливаю через Exception, но хотелось бы это предвидеть чуть раньше... да и вообще отображать текущую, занятую приложением, память...

Comment: На момент вызова конструктора память уже выделена. Можно переопределить NewInstance, и в нем посчитать хватает ли памяти

Comment: @Vasek, приемлемо... а как в нём посчитать?

Comment: Если возник такой вопрос - что-то явно идёт не так. Что за объекты такие?

Comment: @MBo, да нет, всё хорошо, объекты нормальные, не большие. Просто их много, примерно на 15-16млн 4Гб кончаются, сейчас я это визуально только в менеджере задач вижу, хотелось бы видеть в самой программе, ну и чтобы она могла принимать какие-то действия по её освобождению прежде, чем это произойдёт

Comment: Для каждого объекта проверять это накладно. Можно подумать о работе с пулом объектов (маленький менеджер, выделяющий сразу, например, 1000 объектов, и проверка нужна только один раз на эту тысячу)

Comment: @MBo, это я потом подгоню, это мелочи. Мне сам факт интересен, как такая проверка делается... Пусть на 1000.

Comment: Можно создать свой менеджер памяти, который записывает каждое выделение и освобождение, а далее вызывает стандартный менеджер памяти. Но кроме исчерпания количества памяти есть еще проблема с фрагментацией. Суммарно памяти может остаться много, а выделить кусок нужной длины уже не получится.

Comment: Занятую приложением память можно запрашивать через GetProcessMemoryInfo. А свободную, например, через GlobalMemoryStatusEx. Но @ГерманБорисов прав, с выяснением информации о фрагментации будет не всё просто

Comment: Если код однопоточный. Я бы тоже остановился на своем манагере. Но не делал бы его поверх стандартного. Свой алокатор можно очень легко(в однопоточном варианте конечно) написать используя [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) и пару связанных списков. Конечно оверхед по памяти возможно будет больше чем у стандартного. Но считать память в своём алокаторе просче.

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov, с помощью GlobalMemoryStatusEx свободную запрашивать получается, а вот с помощью GetProcessMemoryInfo можно видеть два столбика, которые я выделил, а вот средний, который, собственно, нужен, как получить? https://i.imgur.com/ZzUnG7G.png